# Can't access the Internet in VMware Workstation

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, connection, internet, vmware

I'm using VMware 7.1.2 in Windows 7 with Ubuntu 11.04 as a guest OS.

In the host OS (Windows 7), I can access the Internet without any problems but in the virtual machine I can't access the Internet.

I've tried the following but with no success:

1. Use all methods of connecting to the Internet in "Virtual Machine Settings": `Bridged, NAT, Custom`; none work.
2. Used cabled and wireless connections on the PC - neither of them work.

I've used Ubuntu in VMware for several months - previously the Internet was always accessible. Could the cause of this be because I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: Have you tried to switch on windows network sharing (in adapter options) ?

Comment: Do you get an IP in the guest OS from any of the connection methods (NAT or Bridged)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select bridged networking for the VM.
2. Reboot the VM.
3. Troubleshoot networking in the VM as if it were a real PC on your
   network that can't connect to the Internet. As an example:

   1. What
      does `ifconfig -a` say? Do you have a real IP address from your network? If you use static IPs, then go configure one for this VM in Ubuntu.
   2. Can you ping the host's (Win7) IP address from the guest?
   3. Can you ping the private address of your router or default gateway? 3d) Can you ping www.superuser.com?

It's likely something in your guests network settings changed, maybe it thinks you have a new network card, maybe name resolution isn't working, maybe some firewall settings changed.

Answer (score 0):

Coud it be that DNS has been clobbered? Can you SSH into this machine locally, but not ping, say, google.com? Check /etc/resolv.conf and tell us what you have in there. Is it 127.0.0.1 or something usable?